# PHP mysql_query where x = $this or $that

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-select-db

I currently have a mysql_query line that looks like this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * from users WHERE id = '". $id1 ."' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

However, I want to select everything from users where id = $id1 OR $id2. How would I edit this line to do so?

I've thought about just having two copies of this line, one with $id1 and one with $id2. However, I'm sure that there is a more efficent way to accomplish this. I'm very new to SQL.

Comment: Trivial: `WHERE id = X OR id = Y`, or more extendable: `WHERE id IN (X,Y)`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE FIND_IN_SET('X,Y', id) > 0` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Answer (score 0):

The answer is almost in your question. You should change the query into this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * from users WHERE id = '". $id1 ."' OR id = '" . $id2. "'")
```

You should however not be using the `mysql_*` functions anymore, since they are deprecated. Use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/mysqli) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/pdo) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IN clause just like the example below.

```
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE id IN ( 250, 220, 170 );
```

Answer (score -1):

Your query statement can be something like

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN('{$id1}','{$id2}')";
```

or,

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM usrs WHERE id = '{$id1}' or id = '{$id2}'";
```

**mysql_*** is officially deprecated, so use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php%E2%80%8E) to query your statements.